# Python3 won't find a module even though it is properly installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth, pip, pybluez

I'm using a Python 3.6.7 venv and I have installed the `PyBluez` bluetooth library, in addition to ALL of its dependencies such as `sudo apt install bluetooth libbluetooth-dev python3-bluez` . When I run my python script, I'm getting:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bluetooth'

The crazy part is that I've just checked my environment's `/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` directory and there is ***indeed*** directories entitled bluetooth and a PyBluez-0.22,egg-info.

even still, when I go into the `bluetooth` directory, there is ***indeed*** a `ble.py` file, a `_bluetooth.cpython.so` file (name abbreviated), **and** a bluez.py, all with valid code in them. All dependencies were installed via `pip3 install` from within the virtual environment and even verified with `python3 -m pip install` to which python3 claimed they were already installed. Additionally, `ls -la` shows drwxrwxr-x just like every other dependency in the `site-packages` folder. What is the problem here?

Note: I've also verified install with `pip3 list` from inside the venv.

Note2: Visual Studio Code seems to not be able to locate the modules... They are underlined in red and pylint extension says `unable to import [modulename]`. This is only true for modules installed in the venv. This may just be an error with pylint extension searching the system libs rather than my vent's libs... Not a big deal.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but did you activate the venv ?

Comment: Yes sir, it was active during the entire dependency install process, as noted by the (myenv) prefix to my shell

Answer (score 0):

As you installed `python3-bluez` as apt package, this is installed in the global site packages of your system. By default, virtualenv doesn't inherit packages from global site packages, so inside a virtualenv environment you can't actually import any module from global site packages. But this can be enabled to inherit from global site package on creation of virtualenv environment with `--system-site-packages` flag or after creation by removing `no-global-site-packages.txt` from `lib/pythonX.X/` directory. For more information please follow the official [documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/#the-system-site-packages-option).